# partial fraction and relative prime

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

> [image]

> [image]

Everytime when I encounter such problem, I would decompose it straight away. In the solution sheet, I have no idea why does does those polynomials would be relative prime, and is it important that it has to be relative prime to employ partial fraction?

Anyone comments would be appreaciated!

Comment: It is not important that they are relatively prime to do partial fraction decompositions, but it does complicate matters. For a simple example, consider what happens with $\frac{x+3}{x\cdot x}$. Clearly, you can't decompose this as $\frac Ax + \frac Bx$ for polynomials $A, B$.

Comment: Yes, the polynomials have to be relatively prime. If they are not, then you can always factor out the common factor. You can prove that the rational function can be written as a sum of rational fractions with only relatively prime denominators. If the denominators are not relatively prime, you may not be able to find a partial sum.

Comment: @Kaind I see. Is that all just about the one is not the factor of another? This sufficient to say they are relatively prime?

Comment: Coprime implies no common factors apart from 1. So $(x-1)(x-2)$ and $(x-1)(x-3)$ are not coprime, but neither is one a factor of the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is based upon the following statement:

**Theorem:** If $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are two relatively prime polynomials over a field $K$, if $a$ is the degree of $g(x)$ and $b$ that of $h(x)$, and if $f(x)$ is an arbitrary polynomial of degree less than $a+b$, then an identity $f(x)=r(x)g(x)+s(x)h(x)$ exists, where $r(x)$ is of degree $<b$, and $s(x)$ of degree $<a$.

Note that it follows from this theorem that$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)h(x)}=\frac{r(x)}{h(x)}+\frac{s(x)}{g(x)};$$so, this gives as a partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)h(x)}$.

On the other hand, if you have a finite set of polynomials, then they are relatively prime if and only if no two of them have a common root.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know what are coprime when it comes with numbers or integers. It's a bit puzzling for me when it becomes polynomial.

Comment: Co-prime means that they have no common non-constant factor. For instance, $x^2+x-2$ and $x^3-x^2+x-1$ are not co-prime, since $x-1$ is a factor of both of them.

Comment: all good. Cheers